# How to use menu items text as variable in Elementor Mega Menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

How do I use menu item's text e.g "Jewelry" automatically as variable in menu item's URL making it a dynamic URL ?

I have asked ChatGPT for answer, no luck so far.

[image: elementor dynamic URL]

Answer (score 0):

> You Should Intall [WP Heaer & Footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer-elementor/) Plugin in Your Wordpress.

Then,

You Can Use The Menu Widget in Your Elementor Page Builder And Select The Menu Easily Which You Created in Wordpress Dashboard, **Appearance > Menus**.

Comment: The menu created using shortcode from active theme

Comment: Then, It;s too easy simple use Shortcode Widget And Put The Shortcode Which Theme Created.And, Your Meun Have Been Published...

Comment: no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Search The Shortcode In Your Elementor Page Builder & Add This Widget on Your Page Where You Want To Publish The Menu, OR Check The Image in The Answer